# Mongoose/MongoDB find Document with array of objects by multiple values

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the following document structure:

```js
recipients: [
    {
        name: String,
        hidden: Boolean,
    },
    {
        name: String,
        hidden: Boolean,
    },
    // more ...
];
```

I want to query all documents for a given `name` and a given `hidden` value **in the same object**, meaning at the same index of the recipients array. How can I query for example "all documents for name = test and hidden = false" (where hidden is in the same object as the name)? I tried the following

```js
const chats = await Model.find(
            {
                'recipients.name': name,
                'recipients.hidden': false,
            },
```

But this still returns the document because it does not seem to use those 2 conditions for the same object, but across all objects in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, got it. See the MongoDB docs for `$elemMatch` (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#array-of-embedded-documents)

```
{ 
    "recipients": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "name": name,
            "hidden": false 
        }, 
    }, 
}
```